# Partial string searches with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro for searching for and displaying rows of data based on a search term that is a partial string (typically 4 characters of potentially 16), am a complete beginner at this but so far I have the following (with help from Gord):

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    .Rows.Hidden = False    'unhides all rows
End With
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C1000")
    If cell.Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value Then _
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
Range("A1").Select  'ready for next value input
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can I define the search term as a partial match not an exact match and loose case senstivity?

TIA

Duncan

The data string has no special characters only 0-9 and A-Z so presumably the Like function will suit the task. If so how would the macro change? Apologies but am total newbie at this.
It tried editing: 
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
to: If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value like "*" Then
but no result

Answer (score 2):

First try to convert both your strings (needle and haystack) to `LCASE()` and then use `LIKE` operator. As in example below

```
if lcase(haystack) like "*" & lcase(needle) & "*" then
'do something
```

which will works little like regexp. So it will look into string haystack if contains *needle*. Where * means everything (or nothing). Is this clear?

Comment: Many thanks Lubos, I follow the logic but not sure of where I need to edit the macro. The case sensitivity is not critical, am more concerned at getting the partial match sorted so should this line If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then now be reading If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value like "*" Then?

Comment: @duncan297 Right now you're testing your hide-condition like this: `cell.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value`. Replace this part with whatever solution you like, using `cell.Value` as haystack.

Comment: @duncan297 can you please update your question with this point? in comment its harder to read. But you need to use `Like` or or `instr` (as Verzweifler mentioned) instead other comparison operator. If you use = you checking if two variables are same, if you use <> they are not same, so instead of this you can use like, to check it partialy

Answer (score 2):

Since we can't know if you needle contains `like`-sensitive characters like `#` or `?`, I'd suggest a solution via [instr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
if instr(lcase(haystack), lcase(needle)) > 0 then
' Do Stuff
```

This gives you the starting position of the first occurrence of `needle` in `haystack`, or 0 if `needle` is not found.

Comment: good point, but i think, that VBA ignores `like`-sensitive characters in variable, but not sure with it. You gave me good point to think about :p

Comment: I'm pretty sure VBA doesn't ignore those characters. I've used `like` to build custom searches based on these Expressions.